# Is it possible to amplify the sound from an application, without increasing the system volume?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have searched the web, but and the solution proposed in this web site was increasing the system volume and the applications volume in the Audio Volume Mixer of Windows. But this solution has a serious problem. I have a podcast application whose sound level is so low (to be fair, this is not the problem of the application itself, but of the particular podcast), its sound is only sufficiently loud when I set the Window's system volume to 100. I can then now lower each and every other application's audio volume in the Mixer (this is already tedious), but newly launched apps after that will inherit the full 100 volume. This could cause a serious potential problem, if I start an application later, and forget to lower its volume in the Mixer, and the application starts a normal sound at that maximum loudness.

Is there any utility that can increase the audio volume from a specific app only? I do not mean amplifying the sound over the system volume's maximum loudness; that is impossible. But an app can sound to the maximum loudness within that, right? I am not sure if I explained this well, but if the system volume is set to 50, and at this sate the audio can rage from 0DB to 50DB, and an app is outputting audio at 25DB, it can be increased to 50DB.

If this is not possible due to Window's architecture, I think I could download the podcast MP3 individually and then play it with VLC which has an in-built volume amplify feature, but that would be cumbersome.

Comment: So what application are you using to play the  podcast?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a browser you could use a equalizer extension.

If you are in firefox you can use: https://addons.mozilla.org/es/android/addon/audio-equalizer-wext/?src=search

Answer (score 0):

I do this way: I set the system volume to about half, then I level all the application (in windows system audio) to the half. Doing so I have room to increase or decrease the volume around the average without impagting the "general" setup. Using system's volume up/down just moves the collective level without impacting the "offset" between various applications. In my case I have low system's sounds, normal zoom conference with a little background music:

[image]

When adjusting system volume I still keep system's sounds < vlc < meeting